# Program will not do calculations

Tags: java

```
int single = 0, doub=0, triple=0, homer=0, atbats=0, totalbase, totalhits;
double slug, battingavg;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter singles (-1 to end):  ");
single = sc.nextInt();

while (single != -1)
{
    System.out.print("Enter doubles:  ");
    doub = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter triples:  ");
    triple = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter home runs:  ");
    homer = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter total at bats:  ");
    atbats = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the player's name: ");
    String name = sc.next();
    totalbase = (single + doub * 2 + triple * 3 + homer * 4);
    slug = totalbase / atbats;
    battingavg = (single + doub + triple + homer) / atbats;
    System.out.println("Player's name is " + name);
    System.out.printf("The slugging percentage is %.3f\n", + slug);
    System.out.printf("The batting percentage is %.3f\n", + battingavg);

    System.out.print("Enter singles (-1 to end):  ");
    single = sc.nextInt();
}
```

This program will only output a 1 or a 0 after the calculations. Everything else works fine, but It just doesn't seem to do the calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you do integer divisions, you'll get integer values. Instead use `double` or `float` data types. I see `slug` and `battingavg` are already `double`s, but you're assigning the result of an integer division to them. If you cast at least one of the values in your calculations to a `double` you should get the output you expect. Example:

```
slug = totalbase / (double) atbats;
battingavg = (single + doub + triple + homer) / (double) atbats;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you divide integer values and store the result in a `double` that is a widening conversion, but the value was calculate as an integer and thus you're widening the integer value.

Change this,

```
slug = totalbase / atbats;
battingavg = (single + doub + triple + homer) / atbats;
```

to something like this,

```
slug = ((double) totalbase / atbats);
battingavg = ((double) (single + doub + triple + homer) / atbats);
```

to get `double` values into your `double` variables.